# adding a new route to node express

Tags: node.js, routes, express

I'm trying to add a new route in my express app but I keep getting error when trying to start the server. The error is

```
C:\development\node\express_app\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:252
    throw new Error(msg);
          ^
Error: .get() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]
```

here are my files, I'm new to node so let me know if i left out an important file

routes/furniture.js

```
exports.furniture = function(req, res){
   res.render('furniture', { title: '4\267pli' });
};
```

routes/index.js

```
/*
 * GET home page.
 */

exports.index = function(req, res){
  res.render('index', { title: '4\267pli' });
};
```

views/furniture.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>4&middot;pli -- architecture</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css'/>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Didact+Gothic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <h1 class="logo"><%= title %></h1>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , user = require('./routes/user')
  , furniture = require('./routes/furniture')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path');

var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
  app.use(require('stylus').middleware(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/users', user.list);
app.get('/furniture', routes.furniture);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The trouble is:

```
 routes = require('./routes'),
 user = require('./routes/user'),
 furniture = require('./routes/furniture'),
```

These 3 are setting your routes folders, not a specific file, express will look for a index.js ( not found, then --> error)

Inside these folders, you should put a index.js with your:

```
exports.xxxx =  function(req, res){
    res.render('xx', { foo: foo});
};
```

Then, your project folder structure should look like:

```
routes/
  ├── index.js
  │
  ├── user/
  │     └── index.js (with a exports.user inside)
  │   
  └── fourniture/
        └── index.js (with a exports.furniture inside)
```

You can add **multiple export functions** to a route like these:

app.js

```
// a folder called routes with the index.js file inside
routes = require('./routes')

.
.
.

app.get('/', routes.main_function);  
app.get('/sec_route', routes.sec_function);
app.post('/other_route', routes.other_function);
```

/routes/index.js

```
exports.main_function =  function(req, res){
    res.render('template1', { foo: foo });
};

exports.sec_function =  function(req, res){
    res.render('template2', { bar: bar });
};

exports.other_function =  function(req, res){
    res.render('template1', { baz: baz });
};
```

Comment: @3boll  what if you wanted to have several functions under user...  index.js admin.js and foo.js... how would you write that?

Comment: it also seems that the user = require('./routes/user') can also relate to a user.js file that is held in the routes folder

Comment: oh dear is a bad idea a @Cmag and 1dolinski says but it has so many approvals.

Answer (score 6):

If your website is so big some times I prefer to do something like:

`routes/furniture.js`:

```
module.exports = function(app)
{
    app.get("/furniture/", function(req, res) {
        res.render('furniture', { title: '4\267plieee' });
    });
}
```

And then in `app.js`:

```
require("./routes/furniture")(app);
```

It's mainly the same but app.js will be cleaner.

Comment: This is definitely a nice method as it actually keeps the HTTP routes themselves within the routes folder.

Answer (score 2):

Although this is somewhat old, though of sharing the way i do this. Here is a another approach which makes code more cleaner and easy to add routes.

**app.js**

```
const app = express();
const routes = require('./routes');
app.use('/api', routes); //Main entry point
```

**/routes/index.js**

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const user = require('./user');
const admin = require('./admin'); 

//This is a simple route
router.get('/health-check', (req, res) =>
    res.send('OK')
);

router.route('/users')
      .post(validate, user.createUser);

router.route('/users/:userId')
      .get(validateUser, user.getUser)  
      .patch(validateUser, user.updateUser)
      .delete(validateUser, user.deleteUser);

router.route('/admins/:adminId/dashboard')
      .get(validateAdmin,admin.getDashboard);

module.exports = router;
```

'validateUser' and 'validateAdmin' are custom middle wares, which will be used to validates request parameters or to do some pre-processing before request reach the actual request handler. This is optional and you can have multiple middleware (comma separated) as well.

**/routes/user.js**

```
module.exports = {
  createUser:function(req,res,next){

  },
  updateUser:function(req,res,next){

  },
  deleteUser:function(req,res,next){

  }
}
```

**/routes/admin.js**

```
module.exports = {
  getDashboard:function(req,res,next){

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Follow a simple and consistent folder structure, then use a module to have everything done automatically.

> Then never look back. Spend time saved on the rest of the important stuff.

### TL;DR

```
$ npm install express-routemagic --save
```

```
const magic = require('express-routemagic')
magic.use(app, __dirname, '[your route directory]')
```

That's it!

### More info:

### How you would do this? Let's start with file structuring:

```
project_folder
|--- routes
|     |--- nested-folder
|     |     |--- index.js
|     |--- a-file-that-doesnt-share-same-name-with-another-folder.js
|     |--- index.js
|--- app.js
```

### In app.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const magic = require('express-routemagic')
magic.use(app, __dirname, 'routes')
```

### In any of your routing files:

#### For e.g., index.js

```js
const router = require('express').Router()

router.get('/', (req, res) => { ... })
router.get('/something-else', (req, res) => { ... })
```

#### Or a-file-that-doesnt-share-same-name-with-another-folder.js

> Usually you might want to start a folder and use the `index.js`
>   pattern. But if it's a small file it's okay.

```js
const router = require('express').Router()
const dir = 'a-file-that-do-not-have-another-folder-with-same-name' // you can use this to shorten, but it's optional.

router.get(`$(dir)/`, (req, res) => { ... })
router.get(`$(dir)/nested-route`, (req, res) => { ... })
```

*Disclaimer: I wrote the package. But really it's long-overdue, it reached my limit to wait for someone to write it.*